# Stuck on an Integral Identity and need a hint

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Say we know for a fact that 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} u(r,\theta)r d\theta = 0
$$

can we show that 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}u^2\sin(\theta)d\theta = 0.
$$

I tried using a past question yesterday on stack exchange using properties of functions that are $0$ on an interval, since I know $\sin$ is $0$ integrated over a full period. Upon trying integration by parts it also led nowhere.

I don't want a full solution just a hint would help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Check $u(r,\theta) = \theta^2 - \frac{4\pi^2}{3}$.

Comment: This seems to be a specific example, but is there a way to show that this identity works for all $u$ such that $u$ satisfies our above integral?

Comment: @wjmccann I believe my example shows it works for the first integral (which you should be able to easily confirm), but not the second (e.g., WA gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2-4%28pi%5E2%29%2F3%29%5E2+sin+x+from+0+to+2pi)). This shows you won't be able to prove what you're asking, i.e., it *doesn't* work for all $u$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan If $u(r,\theta)$ was constrained to be periodic would the problem statement then hold? Suppose it satisfies the laplace equation

Comment: @Denis28 I'm quite certain just having $u(r,\theta)$ being constrained to be periodic would not necessarily be sufficient, although I can't offhand think of any particular counter-example. Nonetheless, any periodic $u$ with a period of $\pi$ will always work (I trust you can fairly easily confirm this yourself). As for satisfying the Laplace equation, it's been far too many years since I last studied & used that concept for me to be able to recall enough to give you an answer.